# AWS QuickSight : Effective Read User Maintenance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Now we're verifying QuickSight connected to Redshift, and we estimate over 200 Read User for our QuickSight in the near future.

I'm just wondering is there any appropriate way to create Read Users and send invitation, not one by one manual creation on AWS management console.

We can manage those Read Users by IAM, but not supposed to access to AWS Management Console and each user has onw e-mail address.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just F.Y.I.

I updated Windows AWS CLI to 1.16.96, which version corresponds with QuickSight API.
And manage the QuickSight users by script as follows;

-- Register User

```
aws quicksight register-user --aws-account-id=xxxxxxxxxxxx --namespace=default --email=xxx@xxxx.co.jp --identity-type=QUICKSIGHT --user-name test_user --user-role=READER
```

-- Add Group & User

```
aws quicksight create-group --aws-account-id=xxxxxxxxxxxx --namespace=default --group-name="Sales-Management" --description="Sales Management"
aws quicksight create-group-membership --aws-account-id=xxxxxxxxxxxx --namespace=default --group-name=Sales-Management --member-name=test_user
```

-- Delete User

```
aws quicksight delete-user --aws-account-id=xxxxxxxxxxxx --namespace=default --email=xxx@xxxx.co.jp --identity-type=QUICKSIGHT --user-name test_user
```

There seems to be minor issue : The invitation mail is NOT sent by this command as my expectation. But you can re-send it by GUI management console.

Even though with this minor issue, we can handle large number of users by scripts easily anyway.

Best Regards;